# How to create a square button from the image using gtk+-3.0 and C?

Tags: c, image, button, gtk, gtk3

I have never used Gtk3 before, but from what I see so far there are not so many examples.

Problem: I have a square image that I want to be the button.

What I’ve done so far:

- created button within the aspect frame with ratio 1.0;
- hid the outline of the frame;
- created image from the pixbuf of an image file;
- added image to the button;

Now I probably need to scale the pixbuf to the size of the button. But it all feels unnecessary complicated, not to mention that I’m not really sure how to do this.

Can you explain me, what’s the right way of creating a square button from the image?

Comment: Do you really need the aspect frame? I would expect that you only need to [create](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkImage.html#gtk-image-new-from-file) an appropriately-sized `GtkImage` and add it into the button. If the size of the image is different than the desired size of the button, you need to specify the desired size when [loading](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/2.36/gdk-pixbuf-File-Loading.html#gdk-pixbuf-new-from-file-at-scale) the pixbuf.

Comment: @user4815162342 I’m not sure if I’m doing the right thing. I need my button to fill the entire space given, but at the same time remain square-shaped. Aspect frame seems to do the job just fine. I’m not sure how to make image fill the entire button. Both button and image have ratio of 1.0.

Comment: The question specifies that the code you have feels unnecessarily complicated. If the image has a ratio of 1.0, I would expect that creating a pixbuf using [`gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file_at_scale()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/2.36/gdk-pixbuf-File-Loading.html#gdk-pixbuf-new-from-file-at-scale), then creating a `GtkImage` from the pixbuf and adding it to the button should work fine, while requiring a minimal amount of code. Have you tried that approach?

Comment: @user4815162342 yes, i got rid of the aspect frame. Thank you.